# What is F# equivalent of C# "public event "

Tags: events, com, f#, delegates, c#-to-f#

I'm trying to translate to F# code from this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35532/C-COM-Object-for-Use-In-JavaScript-HTML-Including

I've stumbled on this lines:

```
public delegate void MyFirstEventHandler(string args);
public event MyFirstEventHandler MyFirstEvent;
```

I've tried to translate this in F# as:

```
type MyFirstEventHandler = delegate of string -> unit
type MyFsComComponent () = 
    let my_event = new Event<MyFirstEventHandler,string> ()

    [<CLIEvent>]
    member x.MyFirstEvent = my_event.Publish
```

And I get: **'MyFirstEventHandler' has a non-standard delegate**

I can compile with:

```
type MyFirstEventHandler = delegate of obj*string -> unit
```

But this is not what needed in COM-control.

*This question is also raised in [C# to F# class transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901510/f-classes-cheat-sheet) - "public event" still did not have solution*

**SOLVED. Thanks to Leaf Garland**

```
type MyFirstEventHandler = delegate of string -> unit
type MyFsComComponent () =    
    let my_event = new DelegateEvent<MyFirstEventHandler> ()

    [<CLIEvent>]
    member x.MyFirstEvent = my_event.Publish
```

does the trick.

Comment: Glad that worked for you. You could mark my answer as accepted to highlight it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [F# Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233189.aspx) class expects the argument types as generic parameters, not the delegate type. It also expects that the delegate is a standard type (e.g. something like `obj*eventargs->unit`). For arbitrary delegates use DelegateEvent.

```
type MyFirstEventHandler = delegate of string -> unit
type MyFsComComponent () = 
    let my_event = new DelegateEvent<MyFirstEventHandler>()

    [<CLIEvent>]
    member x.MyFirstEvent = my_event.Publish
```

Comment: I've tried this. 
It's a correct CLIEvent, but it is not full equivalent to C# public event.

COM-magic [<ComSourceInterfaces(typeof<IFsComEvents>)>] do not want to expose it as COM event.

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed that. You can use `DelegateEvent` instead then. I will update answer.

Comment: Leaf, DelegateEvent is exactly what needed.

Comment: Note, `DelegateEvent` is not an implementation of `IEvent` so it is not so well integrated into F#. You might want to work with an `Event<'arg>` type internally (or `IObservable`) and then expose a `DelegateEvent` just for your external COM needs.