# Multiple parameter event type without boxing in F#

Tags: events, f#, delegates, clr, c#-to-f#

The C# equivalent of what I'd like to declare is simple:

```cs
public event Action<DateTime, int> example;
```

I wish to subscribe to this event from C# as follows:

```cs
example += DoSomething;

private static void DoSomething(DateTime time, int count)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Time: {0} Count:{1}", time, count);
}
```

I can use `DelegateEvent`([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169757/what-is-f-equivalent-of-c-sharp-public-event/17170533#17170533)), but my understanding is that [`DelegateEvent.Trigger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340381.aspx) will result in the boxing of the values, as they're passed in as an object array.

How can I define an event of multiple parameters **without boxing** in F#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concrete implementation of `DelegateEvent` does box the arguments into an `obj[]`, but you can create your own `IDelegateEvent` type instead:

```
type T() =
    let handlers = ResizeArray<System.Action<System.DateTime,bool>>()
    let event = { new IDelegateEvent<_> with
                        member __.AddHandler(h) = handlers.Add h 
                        member __.RemoveHandler(h) = handlers.Remove h |> ignore }
    [<CLIEvent>]
    member x.example = event
    member x.Trigger(dt,i) =
        for handler in handlers do
            handler.Invoke(dt,i)
```

If this is something you'll do a lot, then you could encapsulate the logic into its own `CustomEvent` type rather than spreading it through the type containing the event.

Answer (score 1):

```
[<Struct>]
type MyEventArgs(date:DateTime,number:int) =
    member x.Date = date
    member x.Number = number

type MyClass() =
    let e = new Event<_>()
    [<CLIEvent>]
    member x.OnEvent = e.Publish
    member private this.FireEvent (s:DateTime) (i:int) = 
        e.Trigger (MyEventArgs(s,i))
```

Then from C#:

```
namespace Test
{
  class MainClass
  {
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
      MyClass c = new MyClass ();
      c.OnEvent += (object sender, MyLib.EventArgs a) =>   
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from F#");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: While this does correctly avoid boxing, it still causes heap allocations due to the use of a tuple, which is a reference type.

Comment: While your new method of defining a custom struct for each event does avoid the heap allocation, two new problems arise: a) It doesn't actually answer the question about _multiple parameters_ without a heap allocation. b) I'd have to define a struct for each event with a different signature of more than one parameter (and there's quite a few of these).

Comment: @Varon :Make the struct generic,